# Subquery reference newly created column

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to write a subquery based on the [SQL Server docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx). I am trying to write a SQL Server query to

1. cast a varchar to an int
2. select rows where the varchar is null.

My logic is:

1. outer select+ where clause gets all rows where the new column (q5int) is NULL
2. create inner select that performs the cast and creates the new column (q5int)

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate an explanation of whats wrong with my logic, not just how to fix my code.

```
select *  
from 
    (select 
         *, cast (NULLIF(q5,'NULL') as int) as q5int 
     from 
         ft_merge)
where
    q5int = NULL
```

Comment: You also shouldn't compare nulls with `=`.

Comment: WHERE q5int IS NULL

Comment: BTW if 2012+ use try_convert(int,q5)   it will return a null value when the conversion fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us analyze your query first

```
               select *  from (
                select *,cast (NULLIF(q5,'NULL') as int) as q5int 
                from ft_merge
                ) WHERE q5int=NULL
```

1.NULLIF(q5,'NULL') should be NULLIF(q5,NULL) not in quotes

2.WHERE q5int=NULL should be replaced with "q5int IS NULL"

Creating test data

```
       Select * into #ft_merge
        from
        (

              Select 1 AS ID,'111' AS q5
              union
              Select 2, null
                  union
              Select 3,'2222'
                  union
              Select 4,null 
        )t



       /* using your query */  
       select *  from (
      select *,cast(q5 as int) as q5int 
        from #ft_merge where ISNUMERIC(q5) > 0 or q5 is null
      )t WHERE q5int is NULL
      /* another optimal way of doing this */

      select *,cast(q5 as int) as q5int 
      from #ft_merge where NULLIF(q5,NULL) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this sans the sub-query

```
select *  
 from ft_merge
 WHERE try_convert(int,q5) is null
```